# Need to display rows alternatively in POSTGRESQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a few columns as such:

| Category | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| VIDEOS | 19 |
| VIDEOS | 20 |
| BUSINESS | 10 |
| ENTERTAINMENT | 13 |
| WORLD | 14 |
| WORLD | 15 |
| BUSINESS | 25 |

I want to get results such that no 2 category values should appear consecutively. They can be repeated at a later row. Just that they should not be one after another.
ex: videos in first row and videos in second row need re-arranging. So does world.

| Category | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| VIDEOS | 19 |
| BUSINESS | 10 |
| ENTERTAINMENT | 13 |
| WORLD | 14 |
| BUSINESS | 25 |
| VIDEOS | 20 |
| WORLD | 15 |

Is it possible to make it alternating?
I am working with a PostgreSQL server.

Comment: I don't know of any built-in mechanism in any sql server I've ever heard of, to do what you describe.  To me this sounds like something best handled by the presentation layer - eg, reorder the results after they come out of the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Query:

```
select t1.cat, t1.rank from (
    select 
        cat, 
        rank, 
        row_number() over (partition by cat) as num 
    from your_table
) t1 
order by t1.num;

Result:
VIDEOS          19
ENTERTAINMENT   13
BUSINESS        10
WORLD           14
BUSINESS        25
VIDEOS          20
WORLD           15
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly. Time taken for the query is slightly increased but definitely does what I am looking for thank you so much for helping out!